# MySQL on Ubuntu 12.04 LOCAL_INFILE still disabled

Tags: mysqli, ubuntu-12.04

On Ubuntu 12.04 64bit LTS, including MySQL version 5.5.29 - I am trying a LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE command in mysql, but it fails with

`DB Error (1148) The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version`

I have done the following:

Added `local-infile=1` into the **[mysql]** and **[mysqld]** sections of the /etc/mysql/my.cnf file, and restarted the mysql service;

Added the line option MYSQLI_OPT_LOCAL_INFILE,TRUE into my mysqli initiation:

```
function dbConnect($dbHost, $dbUser, $dbPass, $dbName) {
    $mysqli = new mysqli($dbHost, $dbUser, $dbPass, $dbName);
    $mysqli->options(MYSQLI_OPT_LOCAL_INFILE,TRUE);
    if ($mysqli->connect_error)
        die('DB Connect Error (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') '. $mysqli->connect_error);
    return $mysqli;
}
```

But I am still getting the error? Maybe the Local-infile option has not been compiled in this mysql version?

Comment: Is your server maybe starting with "--local-infile=0" (and ignoring the option in my.cnf)?

Comment: `ps -ef | grep mysql` should show the running mysqld process and all parameters.